# Solutions of this system of differential equations stay in first quadrant

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I show that all solutions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ of
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=x^2+y\sin x,$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=-1+xy+\cos y$$
which start in the first quadrant remain there for all time?

I thought that looking at $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-1+xy+\cos y}{x^2+y\sin x}$$
could help, but I don't know what do with this.

Comment: Well, you know, the title of your question doesn't coincide with actual question inside of it...

Comment: @Evgeny Doesn't my question imply that the solutions must be periodic?

Comment: Of course no :) Just draw the trajectories of linear saddle $x' = x, y' = -y$. Trajectories from the first quadrant don't leave it, but they are all not periodic.

Comment: @Evgeny Thanks for the edit, did not notice that :)

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: if trajectory leaves first quadrant, it must intersect it boundary somewhere. You can easily check that $\lbrace (x, y) \colon \, x = 0, y \geqslant 0 \rbrace \bigcup \lbrace (x, y) \colon \, y = 0, x \geqslant 0 \rbrace$ is invariant set for this system: vector field is tangent to these lines and hence they are invariant. However, because of existence and uniqueness theorem, no trajectory can intersect the boundary of first quadrant.

Comment: This is very, very NEAT!

Comment: @GaussTheBauss Thank you :) I just love that tool. And other bunch of geometric tools too :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was wondering if there is also an answer that doesn't use vector fields and the $dy/dx$ instead?

Comment: You might try the other way: you can check whether $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is positive everywhere at first quadrant except at boundary. But you still have to combine it with the fact trajectories that start at boundary don't leave it -- at least there vector fields are needed.

Comment: @Evgeny $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is not positive e.g. at $(\frac{3\pi}{2},100)$, so your last comment would need some refinement.

Comment: @A.G. Thanks :) I think it's not needed to show this everywhere, since the "real action" happens only near $x = 0$ or $y = 0$. And it's true that $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is positive when $0 < x << 1, \; y > 0$  and $\frac{dy}{dt}$ is positive too when $ x > 0, 0 < y << 1$.